# How do I get the DOM to render changes to computed data in a VUE.js Project

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage, vuetify.js

I was following the firebase storage video tutorial for uploading images, it can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpxHVrpfGgU&feature=youtu.be.

I attempted to build the example app using Vue.JS and Vuetify instead. And I thought I had cracked it. However, the upload progress bar does not render changes to uploadPercentage. I even tried logging uploadPercentage to the console to test that it is changing and t is, it just isn't rendering. Does anyone have any idea why and how I can solve this problem?

My code is below:

```
<template>
  <v-container style="height: 100%;">
      <v-row
        style="height: 30%;"
      ></v-row>
      <v-row
        align-content="center"
        justify="center"
      >
        <h1>Image Uploader</h1>
      </v-row>
      <v-row
        align-content="center"
        justify="center"
      >
        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-progress-linear
            color="deep-purple accent-4"
            rounded
            height="6"
            :value="uploadPercentage"
            id="uploader"
          ></v-progress-linear>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row
        align-content="center"
        justify="center"
      >
        <v-col
          class="align-content-center"
          cols="4"
        >
          <v-file-input
            v-model="file"
            accept="image/*"
            label="choose an image"
            outlined
            @change="onFileChange"
            ></v-file-input>
        </v-col>
        <v-col
          class="align-content-center mt-2"
          cols="2"
        >
          <v-btn
            @click="onUpload"
          >
            Upload
            <v-icon right dark>mdi-cloud-upload</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

```
<script>
import firebase from '@/firebase/init'

export default {
  data: () => ({
    file: null,
    imageURL: null,
    uploadPercentage: 0
  }),
  methods: {
    onFileChange () {
      let reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = () => {
        reader.imagUrl = reader.result
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.file)
    },
    onUpload () {
      // create a firebase storage ref
      var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('public_wall/' + this.file.name)

      // upload file
      var task = storageRef.put(this.file)

      // update progress bar
      task.on('state_changed',

        function progress (snapshot) {
          var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          console.log(percentage)
          this.uploadPercentage = percentage
          console.log(this.uploadPercentage)
        },

        function error (err) {
          console.log(err)
        },

        function completed () {

        }

      )
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: In your template you have `:value="Per"`. What is `Per`?

Comment: sorry this is a typo, fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems.

Firstly this:

```
:value="Per"
```

should be:

```
:value="uploadPercentage"
```

Secondly, your `this` won't be pointing at the correct object inside the `progress` function. If you use an arrow function instead it will preserve the value of `this` to match the surrounding scope:

```js
task.on('state_changed',
  snapshot => {
    var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
    console.log(percentage)
    this.uploadPercentage = percentage
    console.log(this.uploadPercentage)
  },
  // etc.
```

You can confirm this problem using `console.log(this)` inside your function.

There are various alternatives to using an arrow function. For example, you could move that function out to its own Vue method. Vue automatically binds functions in `methods` to the appropriate `this`.

Comment: sorry the per is a typo when i was trying to find a solution, I found something that said that i had to reference immutable data so i had a data object called per which pointed to uploadPercentage, but it didnt help anything

Comment: as for the arrow function, it worked perfectly thank you. Is there documentation you can link which explains scope of objects in functions in detail? Thank you.

Comment: @TomWalsh I'd always start with MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this